# iOS UIDatePicker timezone causes disabled spinner(s)

Tags: swift, ios10, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker that I set `timezone` with `NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: seconds)`. But for some reason the time on UIDatePicker gets disabled first time I set new date, but after I switch the mode back to `.date` it works again.

How can I make this one work always? If I don't set the `timezone` the time never gets disabled, but I need to set time zone on.

Here is my code to set, newDate is a NSDate and adjustment is seconds.

```
        self.timePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: adjustment)
        self.timePicker.setDate(newDate, animated: false)
```

Disabled spinner screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I've got the same problem, did you manage to get over it ? or to understand the reason why the spinner is disable ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, looks to be caused by using a time zone that is not the current time zone, or the time zone of the calendar set on the picker. Got this from UIDatePicker.h

> open var timeZone: TimeZone? // default is nil. use current time zone or time zone from calendar

Fixed by setting the calendar and then the time zone on the picker.

```
let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
cal.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "PST")
self.timePicker.calendar = cal
self.timePicker.timeZone = cal.timeZone
```

Comment: In my case simply assigning the .calendar alone fixed it. Setting the timezone after assigning the calendar caused the spinners to work, but these would automatically revert to the previous values when updated. This was tested on iOS 11.4